# Stack-tracing native-threads after ANR

Tags: android, debugging, android-ndk

Some colleagues and myself have been working on an android app using the android NDK lately. A few times now we have encountered ANR notifications, and most times it is simply due to an infinite loop bug on the main native-thread. In any case, we end up tracing strings to logcat in order to isolate the problem.

Of course, /data/anr/trace.txt contains the stack trace for the main UI thread. But I would be overjoyed if there was some way to find a stack trace for the other native-threads.

That's the question: can anybody advise me of any way that I can receive a stack trace for all the threads after I've suffered a ANR notification? It would be great if there was some way of simply augmenting /data/anr/trace.txt with stack data for the other threads.

Comment: What version of Android are you using?  Recent versions of Android include the native stack dumps automatically.  You can generate a native stack dump of all threads in a process on a rooted device with `adb shell debuggerd -b <pid>` (assuming your device is recent enough to have that feature).

Comment: Thanks for the response @fadden. The devices we're developing on are all running 4.4.2, so realistically this should work. Unfortunately, I keep getting "Error dumping backtrace" errors whenever I try to use it. The PID is correct (I can see it printing in LOGCAT) and the program is compiled with NDK_DEBUG=1. I'll keep having a go for some time.

Comment: Are you running it as root?  (Requires a rooted device, then either `adb root`, or `adb shell` followed by `su` on the device and then the `debuggerd -b` command.)